# How to remove file modification tracking on an Emacs buffer?

Tags: linux, shell, emacs

I have a `*shell*` buffer in Emacs where I get a Linux command line shell interface.  On occasion, I wish to save the buffer's contents to disk for future reference were my session to exit and once having done that, Emacs marks the buffer as modified with a `*` before its name once further shell interactions occur in that session, further, when going to compile files, I'm asked whether to save the buffer before proceeding with the compile as they appear as unsaved changes that might impact the compilation.

My question is whether there is some way in Emacs to disassociate the buffer with a file on disk or somehow mark it as never modified so that I don't get the `*` marking and don't get the notice on compile of unsaved changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution is easy: in that shell buffer, type:

```
(setq buffer-file-name nil)
```

Then with the cursor to the right of the close-paren, do <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-e</kbd> or <kbd>M-x</kbd> `eval-last-sexp`. Then you can erase the expression.

Man!  The attitude of these guys saying "Well, don't do that."  This happens to me all the time when I am looking at a file in the other buffer in the frame and want to rename it by saving it, but I forget that the cursor is in my shell buffer.

Comment: You can evaluate an expression directly with `eval-expression` or `M-:`

Answer (score 0):

Don't make the buffer visit a file. Just save any or all of its content to a file by using command `write-region` (not command `write-file`, which visits the file). See the doc for `write-region`: `C-h f write-region`.

Comment: Yes, but what if the damage has already been done with `write-file`, is there anyway to remove the file modification tracking?

Comment: Kill the buffer. Start a new shell (or whatever) buffer. You can do `M-: (set-visited-file-name nil)` and `(set-buffer-modified-p nil)`, but that won't stop buffer modification from being indicated in the mode line, `save-buffer` from asking if you want to save, etc. As @Vamsi points out, buffer modification is indicated even if you do not save to a file.

Comment: There is no reason to do what you did (`C-x C-s`). Just don't do it again - problem solved. I told you how to save buffer content to a file without visiting the file.

Answer (score 0):

In the buffer you wish to remove the modified flag evaluate the following expression in the minibuffer by pressing `M-:`

```
(set-buffer-modified-p nil)
```

This should toggle the modified flag for the buffer.

Comment: Yes, but if you continue to modify the buffer the flag will turn on again, is there a way to remove the file modification tracking?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question. In this case, one way would be to wrap the compilation process in a function that toggles the buffer modified flag before calling the compilation command. Alternately, you could also write a function that reverts the flag every time emacs is idle (this is how syntax checkers like flycheck give feedback) but this would be more complicated.

Comment: Those are all complex, was really hoping for a way to undo the effect of the `save-buffer` command that causes a buffer to hence forth be tracked for changes, where previously it had not been so tracked.

Comment: When you get the unsaved buffers prompt is it because the `*shell*` buffer is changed or the file you are compiling has unsaved changes ? The `*shell*` will be modified every time you run a command in it even if it is not associated with a file. Cant you just open a new shell buffer anyway ?